# Can I emit event in function modifier?

Tags: solidity

I would like to emit event in function modifier. Is it legitimate to do so in solidity?

Here is a event and a modifier

```
uint timeStamp;

event beforeTimeStamp();

modifier NotTooLate() {
  require(timeStamp > now);
  emit beforeTimeStamp();  //can I emit event here in modifier?
  _;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is legal and works just fine. Here's a quick sample contract I used to test it:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract Test {

    uint timeStamp = 4;

    event beforeTimeStamp();

    modifier NotTooLate() {
      require(timeStamp > 2);
      emit beforeTimeStamp();  //can I emit event here in modifier?
      _;
    }

    function sample() NotTooLate  external {

    }

}
```

Comment: That's cool. I got a question - can I log or document the case where timeStamp < 2? In that case the transaction gets reverted with all the events along the way